# Google App Engine-Ajax refresh from datastore using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application(developed in python) that requires a refreshed view from the datastore after every 5 seconds. I have came out with an javascript function and handle the refresh using ajax.

Ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>      <script type="text/javascript">             var refreshId = setInterval(function()          {           $('#responsecontainer').fadeOut("slow").load('/refresh').fadeIn("slow");            }, 5000);       </script>
```

After which, I have a set of div tags(responsecontainer) that enclosed the parameters returned from the server side for display.

```
<div id="responsecontainer">
    {% for greeting in greetings %}
      {% if greeting.author %}
        <b>{{ greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote:
        <a href="/sign?key={{ greeting.key.id }}&auth={{ greeting.author.nickname }}">Delete</a>
      {% else %}
       An anonymous person wrote:
      {% endif %}
      <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote>

    {% endfor %}
</div>

      <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook" name="submitGuestBk"></div>

    </form>
```

My server side code is to query the datastore and render the result back to the template file(index.html).

```
class RefreshPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    greetings_query = Greeting.all().order('-date')
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)

    if users.get_current_user():
      url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
      url_linktext = 'Logout'
    else:
      url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
      url_linktext = 'Login'

    template_values = {
      'greetings': greetings,
      'url': url,
      'url_linktext': url_linktext,
      }

    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))
```

However, when I run the application, the results got refreshed together with the html contents such as forms and tables. Together, I am seeing 2 forms after the index.html refreshed by itself every 5 seconds.

Can anybody guide me on the possible cause and solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `load('/refresh')` replaces the contents of the `responsecontainer` div with the loaded HTML.

You therefore need the `RefreshPage` handler to just return that HTML, and not the whole page. For example, it should use a template which just contains this:

```
{% for greeting in greetings %} 
  {% if greeting.author %} 
    <b>{{ greeting.author.nickname }}</b> wrote: 
    <a href="/sign?key={{ greeting.key.id }}&auth={{ greeting.author.nickname }}">Delete</a> 
  {% else %} 
   An anonymous person wrote: 
  {% endif %} 
  <blockquote>{{ greeting.content|escape }}</blockquote> 
{% endfor %}
```

To avoid duplicating that content in both templates, you could potentially make your main template include this sub-template inside the div, for example:

```
<div id="responsecontainer"> 
    {% include "sub_template.html" %} 
</div> 

<form action="/sign" method="post"> 
<div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div> 
<div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook" name="submitGuestBk"></div> 
</form>
```